# Replace values in a column that come after a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to replace values in a column, but only to the values seen after an specific value

for example, I have the following dataset:

```
In [108]: df=pd.DataFrame([[12,13,14,15,16,17],[4,10,5,6,1,3],[1, 3,5,4,9,1],[2, 4, 1,8,3,4], [4, 2, 6,7,1,8]], columns=['ID','time,'A', 'B', 'C']) 

In [109]: df
Out[109]: 

   ID  time  A  B  C  
0  12  4     1  2  4
1  13  10    3  4  2
2  14  5     5  1  6
3  15  6     4  8  7
4  16  1     9  3  1
5  17  3     1  4  8
```

and I want to change for column "A" all the values that come after 5 for a 1, for column "B" all the values that come after 1 for 6, for column "C" change all the values after 7 for a 5. so it will look like this:

```
   ID  time  A  B  C  
0  12  4     1  2  4
1  13  10    3  4  2
2  14  5     5  1  6
3  15  6     1  6  7
4  16  1     1  6  5
5  17  3     1  6  5
```

I know that I could use `where` to get sort of a similar effect, but if I put a condition like `df["A"] = np.where(x!=5,1,x)`, but obviously this will change the values before 5 as well. I can't think of anything else at the moment.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with shifted valeus by [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html), compared by dictioanry and for next `True`s is used [`DataFrame.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[12,13,14,15,16,17],[4,10,5,6,1,3],
                 [1, 3,5,4,9,1],[2, 4, 1,8,3,4], [4, 2, 6,7,1,8]], 
                index=['ID','time','A', 'B', 'C']).T


after = {'A':5, 'B':1, 'C': 7}
new = {'A':1, 'B':6, 'C': 5}

cols = list(after.keys())
s = pd.Series(new)
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].shift().eq(after).cummax(), s, axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  time  A  B  C
0  12     4  1  2  4
1  13    10  3  4  2
2  14     5  5  1  6
3  15     6  1  6  7
4  16     1  1  6  5
5  17     3  1  6  5
```

Comment: hello @jezrael, thanks for your answer it is very good, but I think I didn't ask the right question, I have changed it a little bit so it looks more like my actual problem. Would you mind having a look?

Comment: for the new question I changed the replacing values instead of 1,2,3 to 1,6,5 which I think will change the answer a bit

Comment: @FelipeArayaOlea - Sorry, answer was edited.

Comment: you beast! it works like a charm